# What CSS property is causing line breaks between this forms input elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a similar form in bootstrap as the one depicted here: https://demo.yubico.com/u2f?tab=register

Below where it says registering a U2F device, there is three visible `input` elements.

```
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus" />
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Next" />
```

When you view the form, the username and password elements are on completely separate lines, one below the other. I don't see any Bootstrap or custom CSS to indicate that this is happening explicitly anywhere. If you copy the HTML verbatim and include Bootstrap, the elements show up side by side.

Is there some CSS I'm overlooking that's causing a line break between the input elements in the form?

Comment: Please take a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: can you use firebug or IE developer toolbar and inspect the CSS and html?

Comment: By default the html element <input> is an inline element, to get them to appear on a sepearate line you need to give them a style of display: block; Here is an Example https://jsfiddle.net/onh7tyLg/

Comment: widths of inputs (X2) don't fit to width of the form. you should decrease the width of inputs. e.g     width: 190px;

Answer (score 0):

The containing form isn't wide enough for them to both fit on one line

Answer (score 0):

the WRAPPER of those elements is causing that: if you enlarge width - it will show them side by side

[image]